# Laravel mix, call app.js in resources

Tags: laravel

I have a web app with laravel and vuejs. I use laravel-mix and in my webpack.mix.js I have:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
```

In the view I have

```
<script src="{{mix('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

But it still does not run, I think it could be interfered by `<base href="{{asset('')}}">` card.

I run `npm run watch` but still no error message. In my website `app.js` can run but the other libraries get lost.

Answer (score 3):

I always do these steps and it works please try these:

1)install laravel mix `npm i`

2)in webpack :

```
 mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js');
mix.js('resources/assets/js/admin.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
.sass('resources/assets/sass/admin.scss', 'public/css');
```

> please include your css and javascript files in new files like here in admin.js and admin.scss

3)in admin.scss include your css files for example :

```
@import "files/sweetalert.css";
```

4)in admin.js include your js files for example :

```
mix.combine([
    'files/jquery.js',
]);
```

5)in blade include js and css files:

```
<script src='js/admin.js'"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/admin.css">
```

6)run `npm run watch`