# Laravel 6 mix path not work when remove public path

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Laravel 6 mix path not work, when remove public path using htaccess

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

**Link:**

`<script src="{{mix('/js/app.js')}}"></script>`

**Worked:**

`<script src="{{asset('/js/app.js')}}"></script>`

Question:

How can use `mix` ?

Comment: mix generates a file called `mix-manifest.json` in your public directory. Make sure the file you are using matches the keys in that file

Comment: "_when remove public path using htaccess_" There should be no need to remove `public` from the URL, `public` should be the "DocumentRoot" of your server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel mix, call app.js in resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240049/laravel-mix-call-app-js-in-resources)